# How to generate fixed url with ngrok

Tags: ngrok

I am working on Facebook messenger.

My Facebook app only accept one url for a webhook but ngrok is generating a new URL every time. Now I am unable to test my app because the webhook URL has changed.

Comment: UPDATE NOV 2018: See answer below with 39+ upvotes suggesting other services! https://stackoverflow.com/a/47500376/565877

Comment: Update AUG 2023: [Starting today, all users can claim one static domain for free](https://ngrok.com/blog-post/free-static-domains-ngrok-users) -> https://dashboard.ngrok.com/cloud-edge/domains

Answer (score 207):

**UPDATE May 2020**

[Serveo](http://serveo.net/) is up and running again! No installation, no signup!

All you need to do is to run this:

```
ssh -R <unique subdomain>:80:<your local host>:<your local port> serveo.net
```

like

```
ssh -R youruniquesubdomain:80:localhost:8000 serveo.net
```

---

**UPDATE January 2020**

Since there are some issues with [Serveo](http://serveo.net/) and [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel), I want to share with you another free ssh-based self-hosting service: [Localhost.run](http://localhost.run)

Unfortunately, it does not provide unique subdomains but it is ssh-based so you do not have to install additional applications. Still waiting for Serveo coming back.

---

**UPDATE April 2018**

I've found [Serveo](http://serveo.net/) just now! And it is totally incredible!

---

**UPDATE November 2017**

Probably, it is not the best option for you but I started using [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel) instead of [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

An installation and run flow is very simple:

```
npm install -g localtunnel
lt --port <your localhost port> --subdomain youruniquesubdomain
```

Then I can go to my http://youruniquesubdomain.localtunnel.me
That's it!

Comment: As I develop within a docker container, my virtual network runs off a `subdomain.localhost` URL. This tool does exactly what I needed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DazBaldwin I've updated my answer just now. Serveo looks extremely incredible!

Comment: Though it seems like a great service. Serveo doesn't actually work for my needs. I'm not sure if it's because my local env is being served from within a docker container or something but local tunnel seems to be able to handle it.

Comment: "Invalid host header" when serving my angular app.  
All well when serving a separate app...  hmm

Comment: Serveo is great! If you are looking for alternatives, there is also [Burrow.io](https://burrow.io). You create and manage tunnels via web interface, so you don't even need to type ssh commands. Just paste a CURL command and BAM, tunnel opened.

Comment: @PauloArruda unfortunately it is not free :( But thank you for the info. it looks interesting

Comment: localchannel raise an error when you you define a subdomain: tunnel server offline: Request failed with status code 403

Comment: Automatically restart serveo after disconnect with `until ssh -R aw2xcd:80:localhost:5000 serveo.net; do echo "Restarting..."; done`

Comment: Google Chrome detects serveo.net as dangerous. "Warning – visiting this website may harm your computer!".

Comment: Servo is the best. The same URL every time you need. Better than ngrok. I strongly suggest to use it.

Comment: Serveo ... wtf? Free? No install? No signup? Why do people make such amazingly amazing things and then give them to me for free? This just saved me $5/month from ngrok which I was happy to pay. THANK YOU STACK OVERFLOW.

Comment: wow !! just wow you can resuse your domain name again as well. ngrok sucks!!

Comment: Hey, Serveo does sound awesome, but when I run the command just as indicated, I get this when going to the browser: Bad Request - Invalid Hostname, do you know what might be going on?

Comment: @MaximilianoAmbrosini probably that subdomain is occupied by someone else.
I've just tried ssh -R youruniquesubdomaasdin:80:localhost:8000 serveo.net
and it worked just fine

Comment: hmm I definitely used a unique subdomain, I'm not sure if it's related to it using https or something like that.

Comment: Looks promising. Can you set custom host-name header like with ngrok?

Comment: localtunnel is throwing just 404 and serveo is down due issues with phishing by malicious users

Comment: @IvanCastellanos seems like ngrok hackers are trying to take their money back lol

Comment: @IvanCastellanos I have updated my answer. It is not good as Serveo but not bad as ngrok or localtunnel.

Comment: @Qumber This is why I use localhost.run. 
Serveo proved itself as convenient but highly unstable

Comment: @EugeneKovalev Well I've tried localhost.run but it does not give stable sub-domains for free. I found this another service called [PageKite](https://pagekite.net) that lets you setup a subdomain and has a Pay What You Want pricing. Also it felt a bit faster to me.

Comment: The Answer to "How to ...l with ngrok" is not "Install Serveo"

Comment: @David you are always welcome to pay for ngrok billing plans. The link to the one is right below my answer, left by Arvind Pattar.

Comment: Localhost.run works really well 27.01.2022!

Comment: Launched https://srv.us, which might or might not fare better. No account, no spyware (you'll have to trust that I run the code published…), subdomains are unique and persistent.

Answer (score 22):

You need to set up auth token. You can find it here https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth. (W̶o̶r̶k̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶f̶r̶e̶e̶ ̶v̶e̶r̶s̶i̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶a̶y̶ it's now paid feature, see [ngrok pricing](https://ngrok.com/pricing)).

Then you can use it like this:

```
ngrok http 80 --subdomain yoursubdomain
```

Comment: Doesn't works. Still the same error. Tunnel session failed: Only paid plans may bind custom subdomains.
Failed to bind the custom subdomain 'mysubdomain' for the account 'Ck Maurya'.
This account is on the 'Free' plan.

Comment: That's really strange, I'm not paying a penny and I can use subdomain option. Maybe it's only working for some time on new accounts?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @CkMaurya =(

Comment: What version of ngrok you are using? I have `ngrok version 2.0.19` installed, and when I run `ngrok http 80 -subdomain yoursubdomain` It works just fine. But as I said, token has to be set up. When I remove my token I'm getting same error. Maybe my account is somehow special, but I'm not paying for it.

Comment: @pbogut are you still able to access it freely?

Comment: Version 2.2.8 gives `ERR_NGROK_313` when running the above command with an authentication token in use.

Comment: Ngrok appears to have changed their pricing. Going to their pricing page shows that "custom subdomains" is a feature available starting on the "Basic" account level. https://ngrok.com/pricing

Comment: Static Ngrok domains for free-plan users are available again -> https://ngrok.com/blog-post/free-static-domains-ngrok-users

Answer (score 18):

No more free subdomain support from ngrok.....pls have a error as below

Tunnel session failed: Only paid plans may bind custom subdomains.
Failed to bind the custom subdomain 'arvindpattartestfb.ngrok.io' for the account 'arvccccc'.
This account is on the 'Free' plan.

Upgrade to a paid plan at: https://dashboard.ngrok.com/billing/plan

ERR_NGROK_313

Comment: Indeed. ngrok message: `Tunnel session failed: Only paid plans may bind custom subdomains... Sign up at: https://ngrok.com/signup. If you have already signed up, make sure your authtoken is installed. Your authtoken is available on your dashboard: https://dashboard.ngrok.com`.

Comment: when did this change and where was the announcement?

Answer (score 9):

Neither localtunnel.me or Serveo are working for me right now so I created a temporary solution that works for some use-cases including mine (react-native local development): using the `ngrok` npm package one can save the generated ngrok url into a json file, and that file can be read for any other app.

First make sure to install ngrok using `npm install ngrok` then use this node script:

```js
const ngrok = require('ngrok');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

(async function() {
  const url = await ngrok.connect(3000);
  const api = ngrok.getApi();
  let data = await api.get('api/tunnels');
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  let dict = {'domain': data.tunnels[0].public_url}
  await fs.writeFile("config.json", JSON.stringify(dict));
  console.log("saved " + data.tunnels[0].public_url);
})();
```

Then from your app you may read it using code similar or equal to:

```js
const backend = require('./config.json').domain;
```

Comment: TypeError: api.get is not a function

Comment: use 
const tunnels = await api.listTunnels();
instead of
api.get
as its deprecated

Answer (score 4):

For DHIS2 local installation, I did this on the terminal on ubuntu server.

Make sure your web is running on the specified port. Mine was on 8080.

> `ssh -R dani.serveo.net:80:localhost:8080 serveo.net`

The beauty of this serveo.net is you can reuse the same hostname prefix url before serveo.net as many time as you want, even if power goes off or internet diconnection.

Answer (score 3):

Staqlab tunnel is providing domain for free. Its works great but need a binary to be downloaded from there website. Using this service for month without any hassle

Answer (score 3):

In 2022 (almost 2023) [pagekite.me](https://pagekite.net/) works for me.
It is very similar to ngrok, and requires the installation of pagekite.py (and, obviously Python).

After installation click on pagekite.py opens pagekite shell.

Run command: `8080 subdomain.pagekite.me`

Comment: But it is not free, it's paid.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that no one mentioned how to have static ngrok urls, which was the main question about.

A way to do it is to edit the ngrok.yml file, which is [located at](https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-agent/config)

```
Linux: "~/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml"
MacOS (Darwin): "~/Library/Application Support/ngrok/ngrok.yml"
Windows: "%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\ngrok\ngrok.yml"
```

You can have content such as:

```
version: "2"
authtoken: valid_auth_token
tunnels:
  first-app:
    addr: 3000
    proto: http
    hostname: yourfixedngrok_id1.ngrok.io
  second-app:
    addr: 8000
    proto: http
    hostname: yourfixedngrok_id2.ngrok.io
```

This will help you expose multiple ports, and have a persisted url for each of which based on the value you set for hostnames.

After that, you run your ngrok using this command:

```
ngrok start --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Though its not a solution but take it as workaround, I had the same problem while testing. What i did is keep the ngrok running with my http port, so my ngrok url is not changing. but I frequently changing and restarting my server for testing and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from August 2023, ngrok provides free static domains for everyone.

[Related article](https://ngrok.com/blog-post/free-static-domains-ngrok-users)

Quoting from the article above the steps to claim the domain are

1. Log in to your ngrok account.
2. Navigate to `Cloud Edge > Domains`.
3. Follow the prompts to claim your unique, static domain.

Then you can use it by

```
ngrok http --domain=[static-domain] 80
```