# Ngrok url changes everyday I launch Ngrok

Tags: dialogflow-es, ngrok, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I must switch off my computer when I leave the office, then I have to start `Ngrok` the next day. The surprise is that the `URL` which `Ngrok` gives is different from the one it gave yesterday. So in order to test `Dialogflow` with a `Webhook Fulfillment` I have to change everyday the `URL` ! So how to avoid that situation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate fixed url with ngrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050182/how-to-generate-fixed-url-with-ngrok)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's mentioned [here](https://ngrok.com/docs) that you need to upgrade to a paid plan in order to have a fixed url.

> **Getting a stable URL**
> On the free plan, ngrok's URLs are randomly generated and temporary. If you want to use the same URL every time, you need to upgrade to a paid plan so that you can use the subdomain option for a stable URL with HTTP or TLS tunnels and the remote-addr option for a stable address with TCP tunnels.

Answer (score 4):

Get a paid plan from them. this is how ngrok works when it's free.