# Ngrok free domain setup

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, ngrok

I am just getting started on using ngrok
I have created an app/website on Django and trying to test it using ngrok

So far the process has been

1. ngrok config add-authtoken
2. ngrok http 8000

```
Session Status                online
Account                       XXXXXXX (Plan: Free)
Version                       2.3.41
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://<temp-name>.ngrok-free.app -> http://localhost:8000
Forwarding                    https://<temp-name>.ngrok-free.app -> http://localhost:8000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

where I use https://< temp-name >.ngrok-free.app.ngrok-free.app for my testing

Through the Domains option in the website I have got a free domain thats

```
<some-free-name>.ngrok-free.app
```

how do I setup/run so that ngrok will use this domain, which will greatly help me in the process of testing

I have also tried

`ngrok http -subdomain=< <some-free-name>.ngrok-free.app > 8080`

which does not work when I try and set it up with free service and asks me to pay

Apricate the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate fixed url with ngrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050182/how-to-generate-fixed-url-with-ngrok)

Comment: @Martheen, unfortunately no. the ngrok detials over there are a little old for example I have tried `ngrok http 8000 --subdomain <some-free-name>.ngrok-free.app`
which states that I need to have a paid account to make that work this new

Comment: Ah, okay, might wanna try cloudflare tunnels if you want free persistent route.